# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation Dropdown not extending outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started working with twitter bootstrap. Finding it fairly intuitive. 
But i am having a problem, where the navigation dropdown will not extend outside the container div.

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BwpaX/1/

How can i make the dropdown to extend outside the containg div?

Here is the HTML i am using.

```
  <div class="main2">
  <div class="navbar">  
  <div class="navbar-inner">  
  <div class="container">  
     <ul class="nav">  
       <li class="active">  
         <a class="brand" href="#">example</a> 
       </li>    
      </ul>  
    <ul class="nav pull-right">  
       <li class="dropdown">  
         <a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle menu_col" data-toggle="dropdown"> Tags 
            <b class="caret"></b>  
          </a>  
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
          <li><a href="#">Share</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Tagged</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#">Enjoy</a></li>  
         </ul>  
        </li>  
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>  
      </div>
    <div class="searchbar_analytics">
    <form class="navbar-search pull-right">  
    <i class="icon-search" style="margin-right:3px;"></i><input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search"/>  
    </form>

     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to note. You should make use of Bootstrap's CSS classes. As c-smile mentioned, your main2 class needs to have `overflow: hidden` removed.

I would also suggest adding the `container` class to both search_analytics div and the main div. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BwpaX/2/

Comment: adding container class to both serach_analytics and main2 div...and removing the overflow hidden solved the problem.

Comment: Thnaks... Would you mind telling me what is so special about container class?

Answer (score 1):

You've enclosed your popup into

```
.main2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

no surprise that popup will not be visible outside it. Remove that `overflow:hidden;` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for main2:

```
.main2 {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here the `overflow: hidden;` attribute has been removed allowing and elements inside it too extend over main2's border.